# Concrete5: How to stop macrons disappearing when cache is cleared?

Tags: caching, concrete5

I have a concrete5 site, which uses 'designer content' an add on available via their market place.

Our clients site requires the use of macrons for their language.

Now this is fine throughout 99% of the site, whether hard-coded html or via a content block etc. However, when macrons are used inside a block created with 'designer content' the macron is replaced with a "?"...

Can anyone help?

Unfortunately this site wont let me post an image to help you see whats going on due to my 'low reputation'....riiiiight thats helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually the apparition of question marks "?" instead of certain characters is the sign of a charset coding problem. With C5 you should be using a generic UTF8 encoding however if your database table was set to use a different charset or if your php settings are set to a different charset, then you will get those weird characters.

You should start with your php.ini and set the charset to utf8

If that doesn't fix the problem, check this thread, it has a useful script to use to fix the database
http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/usage/utf-8-or-unicode-problems-preventing-corrrupt-fonts-on-the-front/#52300

Be aware however that if content was saved while the charset was not correct, you may discover that the content still looks weird and you will have to insert it again AFTER having set the correct charset.